# Actionbar overlay not working as expected

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My Android app has a translucent `ActionBar`. It hides when I touch the screen and shows up again when the screen is touched again.

#### /value-11/styles.xml

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="buttonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
</style>
```

When I start the app, the `ActionBar` is translucent, that's the expected state. When I hide it using `getActionBar().hide();` and make it show up again using `getActionBar().show();` it's not translucent anymore.

It's a `Fragment` in a ViewPager. If I just scroll right, hide and show works like expected: the `ActionBar` is translucent after `show();` gets called.

Update: Everytime I scroll left, the bug is there again.

Has anybody an idea how to fix this, so it works also on the first page or when the user has scrolled one or more to the left?

Comment: Hi, can u give some sample code, which is executable. its easy to identify your problem..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved my problem:

The layout of the view inside the ViewPager was the following:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/presentation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:contentDescription="@string/presentation"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
</ImageView>
```

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` was responsible for this weird bug, without this, all works fine.

And sorry for writing so less code, I just thought it was a javacode-issue and not related to the xml. And I could not find a codeblock, that approx. would be the one with the error in it. How should I, the error was in my layout-file. ;)